# Texture problem two sides of a face after a solidify

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv

I have a problem with my blender project.
I modeled a can cut in two to make a kind of boat, but that's not the problem. The problem is that after doing a solidify to give it a thickness, I can not texture only one side of my object, the UV MAPPING is displayed double-sided. I cannot because of the solidify select the other faces inside my can. I put you pictures to better understand the problem.I want a texture in my can and an other texture out of my can. I hope you can help me.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Create your second texture:

[image]

In the *Solidify* modifier > *Materials > Material Offset* choose the slot where the material is, 0 is for material #1, 1 for material #2, etc. You can also choose the rim material:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also make a double sided surface based on normals direction with a backfacing node set-up

[image]

Comment: yes but are you sure it works with a Solidify modifier? I can't make it work...

Comment: Not with the solidify that i know of - you would need to do the extrusion manually and flip the normals. This was just an optional workaround. The material slot is best plan if the solidify is needed or for different rim color etc.